# Automating samba copy at share level with batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I'm copying files to an unreliable samba share using Robocopy

The script below appears to work but I can't test it fully at this stage.

I really have two questions:

1. Can't replicate at share level in robocopy

   I've found that robocopy must have at least `\\host\share` as it's target. If I just use `\\host` it throws ERROR 161. I basically want to replicate a bunch of folders accross into their identically named share. For example my source folders look like this:

   ```
   E:\Root\Folder1\File1
   E:\Root\Folder2\File2 
   E:\Root\Folder3\File3
   ```

   and I want to copy all of that to

   ```
   \\asambashare\Folder1\File1
   \\asambashare\Folder2\File1
   \\asambashare\Folder3\File1
   ```

   In my source, `Folder1` is simply a folder, but in my samba target, `Folder1` is actually a share.

   I'm getting around it now by running a robocopy for each share.

   What I would rather do is loop through folders or find a way to convince robocopy to do it this way rather than explicitly naming all of the folders.
2. Reliable return codes against robocopy

   For my purposes errorlevel 7 and below from robocopy is fine and the batch script should return 0

   Firstly is my current code doing that?

   Secondly if I call robocopy multiple times can I simply repeat the `IF ERRORLEVEL...` code after each call? I want it to try each copt regardless and if at least one failes, the script should return 1

   I believe what I have is pretty close but if someone could answer with certainty it would save me a lot of testing.

   ```
   REM target must be of the format \\host\share. 
   REM Simplest way to do this is list out each combination manually
   REM Afer calling ROBOCOPY, set Exitcode. 
   REM If at least one copy returns 8 or higher, this batch file returns 1. 
   REM Otherwise it returns 0


   SET LOGFILE=E:\SambaReplication.LOG
   SET SRC=E:\Root\asambashare
   SET TGT=\\asambashare
   SET EXITCODE=0


   ROBOCOPY %SRC%\Folder1 %TGT%\Folder1 /S /MOV /R:20 /W:600 /V /FP /LOG+:%LOGFILE%
   IF ERRORLEVEL 8 SET EXITCODE=1

   ROBOCOPY %SRC%\Folder2 %TGT%\Folder2 /S /MOV /R:20 /W:600 /V /FP /LOG+:%LOGFILE%
   IF ERRORLEVEL 8 SET EXITCODE=1

   ROBOCOPY %SRC%\Folder3 %TGT%\Folder3 /S /MOV /R:20 /W:600 /V /FP /LOG+:%LOGFILE%
   IF ERRORLEVEL 8 SET EXITCODE=1



   EXIT %EXITCODE%
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for` command to iterate over the indicated list of folders.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

SET "LOGFILE=E:\SambaReplication.LOG"
SET "SRC=E:\Root\asambashare"
SET "TGT=\\asambashare"
SET "EXITCODE=0"

FOR %%F IN (Folder1 Folder2 Folder3) DO (
    ROBOCOPY "%SRC%\%%F" "%TGT%\%%F" /S /MOV /R:20 /W:600 /V /FP /LOG+:"%LOGFILE%"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 8 SET "EXITCODE=1"
)

ENDLOCAL & EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

And if all the directories under `%SRC%` are to be copied, instead of enumerating them in a list, use the `for /d` to just retrieve the list of folders

```
FOR /D %%F IN ("%SRC%\*") DO (
    ROBOCOPY "%%~fF" "%TGT%\%%~nxF" /S /MOV /R:20 /W:600 /V /FP /LOG+:"%LOGFILE%"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 8 SET "EXITCODE=1"
)
```

Where

```
`%%~fF` is the full path of the folder referenced by `%%F`, and 
`%%~nxF` is the name and extension (if it has) of the folder referenced by `%%F`
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you that works perfectly. One small question if I may. I'd like the log file to always be in the same folder and if possible have the same name as the batch file. So rather than hard code the log I'd like to use some magic squiggles to pick up the batch path and name if possible. Can you suggest some valid code for that?

Comment: @ElectricLlama, `SET "LOGFILE=%~dpn0.log"` where `%0` is a reference to the current batch file, so `%~dpn0` is the drive, path and file name without extension of the current batch file.